# Supported locations for distributing applications

Tags: android

I get the following information from http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=138294

> The developers can also choose free application distribution to users in the "Rest of the world" -- with the option to exclude distribution in the following countries:

One of the excluded distribution country list is my current located location - Malaysia. However, why I am still able to download a bunch of free applications in my current located country? Or, is this Developer Help link outdated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an option to exclude distribution to Malaysia. It is not a requirement. That means developers can decide to not distribute their application in Malaysia, but they will anyways because it's only an option. Not mandatory.

Comment: Opps. I re-read the statement again. Now I get what it means.